# Fixing PHP: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource

Tags: php, mysql

I am getting this error on my wepage

```
Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource
```

This is my code:

```
<?php
require_once("connect.php");

if(isset($_GET['userSearch'])) {
$srch=$_GET['userSearch'];
$allMov = "SELECT * FROM tbl_handbags WHERE handbags_name LIKE '%".
$srch."%' ORDER BY handbags_name";
} else if (isset($_GET['nav'])) {
$select=$_GET['nav'];
$allMov = "SELECT * FROM tbl_handbags, tbl_cat, tbl_l_hc WHERE tbl_handbags.handbags_id=tbl_l_hc.handbags_id AND tbl_cat.cat_id=tbl_l_hc.cat_id AND tbl_cat.cat_name = '".$select."' ORDER BY tbl_handbags.handbags_id ASC";

}
else{
$allMov = "SELECT * FROM tbl_handbags ORDER BY handbags_id ASC";

}

$movResults = mysql_query($allMov);

?>
```

And this is the line with the coding error:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($movResults)){
```

It worked the entire time I was building the site but as soon as I went live it fell apart.

Can someone please help me out??

Thank you

Comment: What condition is the being used when you receive the error, also use mysqli as mysql is depreciated

Comment: Do yourself a favor and use parameterized queries, your code is vulnerable to SQL injections. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php

Comment: `echo mysql_error()` is always helpful.

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to say what exactly is the problem. Please debug your query with `echo $allMov;` and try the query in phpmyadmin or directly in at your mysql console in your live environment. I guess your live database does not have all the tables you created in your development database